# How to set up environmental variable in Ubuntu?

Tags: jdk

I have never used Ubuntu before. How do I go about setting an environmental variable that points to JDK? I installed it on my Desktop. I typed in "EXPORT JAVA_HOME=~/Desktop/jdk" in the command prompt but it didn't work.

Comment: remove "EXPORT"

Comment: make export lower case.

Answer (score 0):

set environment variables as follows

Edit the system Path file /etc/profile

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

Add following lines in end

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

for reference http://javaandme.com